# Decimal to binary converter: add spaces to output

Tags: c, binary, decimal, converters

I'm implementing decimal to binary converter in C. However part of my assignment is to have a space between each 8bits.

For example: 00001000 10101010 11111110 00000001

Here is my code:

```
if(decimal >= 0 && decimal <= 2147483647)
{
    printf("%d as a 32-bit binary number is:\n",decimal);
    for(x=31; x>=0; x--)
    { 
        y = decimal >> x;
        if(y&1)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
    }
}
```

Comment: If `x` is a multiple of 8 then print a space after printing the digit.

Comment: Added language tag. Improved code formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the modulus operator, to say if this is a multiple of 8, then add a space.

```
if (x % 8 == 0) printf(" ");
```

Comment: I think you want `x` not `y`.

Comment: when i do use y%8 every other bit there is a space every other time. and if  i use x%8 it prints the sets as 7bits, 8bits, 8bits, 1bit

Comment: You're right kaylum, but I'm a bit puzzled why Anthony's having trouble. Perhaps you know?

Comment: @anthonymucci As I said in my comment. The above space printing code needs to be put **after** the current code that prints the `1` or `0` digit. If placed before that then the result will be incorrect as you have found.

Comment: Note: In C, `%` is better described as the reminder operator than the modulus operator.